# Haskell - generate and use the same random list

Tags: haskell, random

In Haskell, I'd like to generate a random list of `Int`s and use it throughout my program. My current solution causes the array to be created randomly each time I access/use it.

How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: Generate it once, say in `main`, and then pass it to every function that needs it.  Or (exactly the same, just a different way of phrasing it) use the `Reader [Int]` monad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example (@luqui mentioned) you should be able to generalize to your need:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import System.Random (randomRIO)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  randomList <- randomInts 10 (1,6)
  print randomList
  let s = myFunUsingRandomList randomList
  print s

myFunUsingRandomList :: [Int] -> Int
myFunUsingRandomList list = sum list

randomInts :: Int -> (Int,Int) -> IO [Int]
randomInts len bounds = replicateM len $ randomRIO bounds
```

---

#### remarks

- `randomInts` is an `IO`-action that will produce you your random list of integers, you see it's use in the very first line of `main`s `do`-block. Once it is used there the list will stay the same.
- `myFunUsingRandomList` is a very simple example (just summing it) of using such a list in a pure fashion - indeed it just expects a list of integers and I just happen to call it with the random list from `main`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this [example](https://wiki.haskell.org/Examples/Random_list). Then, pass `rs` from `main` to whatever function needs it.

You can't have a global variable for this without using something like `unsafePerformIO`, which, as the name indicates, should not be used. The reason is that picking random numbers is an inherently non-deterministic operation, dependent on the outside `IO` state.